# What does corei5 and corei7 processor mean?

Tags: operating-systems

I don't find any difference working on corei5 or corei7 processors.Can anyone explain in terms of performance,What are the differnces?

Comment: did u mean how processor works with respective to operating system?

Comment: @sujeet - It means nothing.  Core is what Intel calls their current generation of chips.   i3, i5, and i7 seperate different series of products.  The actual differences are outline on Intel's website.

Comment: You will probably only see differences with some applications... For example, gaming. And this of course depends on whether the application can utilise all the threads which is one of the major differences.

Comment: http://ark.intel.com

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, its just branding and marketing.

In a *very* general way (but not a fixed rules based on specification):

- i7 are quad-core, i5 are dual
- clock speed of i7 are faster than i5
- i7 have larger cache
- HyperThreading is limited to 2 cores for the i5 (so you virtually have 4 cores). A 4-cores i5 will have no HT. i7 up to 6 core have HT (so you virtually have 12 cores)
- You'll find only Intel HD Graphics 3000 and 4000 on i7, no lower GPU model, whereas you can find them on i5 (but you can also have HDG 3000 and 4000 on i5).

Read http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2404675,00.asp for more détails (I extract these lines from this page)

Comment: [i5-750 is quad core...](http://ark.intel.com/products/42915)

Comment: that why I say it mainly marketing, and the rules I described are just "general" ones. ("in a general way"). There are also i7 with 6 cores... But a 4-cores i5 like the 750 have no Hyper-Threading. A four-cores i7 have.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. Without additional informations on the model of the processor and on the architecture of your machine it is impossible to guess why the performances are similar.

For a real comparison you should have the processor installed on the same hardware and with the same operating system and software running.

Theoretically a i7 should be more efficient due to major cache size and to the ability to support Hyper-Threading.

I suggest you to use some CPU performance tool to inspect your processors.

Searching on the net `i5 vs i7` you can find a lot of articles related to this argument (e.g [here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/buying-advice/pc-components/3417091/whats-difference-between-intel-core-i3-i5-i7/) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core) or [here](http://www.techpowerup.com/reviews/Intel/Core_i5_4670K_and_i7_4770K_Comparison/), etc).